# How can I transfer Google Drive's files/folders ownership

Tags: google-drive-api, gmail, google-account

Is there a way to transfer ownership of a folder or file to another Google account?
What sorts of pros and cons are involved here?

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, please mark as correct. ty

Answer (score 1):

Go to Drive or a Docs, Sheets, or Slides home screen.

Open the sharing box:

In Drive: Select the file or folder and click the share icon at the top.

In a Docs, Sheets, or Slides home screen: Open the file and click Share in the top-right corner of the file.

If the new owner already has edit access, skip to Step 4.

Otherwise, follow these steps:

Type the email address of the new owner in the "Invite people" field.

Click Share & save.

(**Step 4**): Click Advanced in the bottom-right corner of the sharing box.

Click the drop-down menu next to the name of the person you want to own the file or folder.

Select **Is owner**.

Click **Done**.

You'll have access to the file as an editor after you transfer ownership.

Google Apps Customers: You can't make someone outside of your domain the owner of your Google Doc.

Only Google Apps customers in Government and Education domains can transfer ownership of a synced or uploaded file (like a PDF or image file).

Consumer Drive users: You can't transfer ownership of a synced or uploaded file (like a PDF or an image file).

Source: [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494892?hl=en%20%22support.google.com)

Comment: this doesn't work recursively, it transfer the ownership of the selected folders.

Comment: @Vincenzooo don’t know of a recursive solution

Answer (score 1):

The only way currently to transfer all subfolders and files inside a folder to another user (except sharing between users of the same Google Apps domain(s) where there is an admin feature for that) is this:

1. Share the folder with the other account
2. Add the folder to the other account's drive
3. Run the following Google Apps Script on that folder:

`

```
function copyfoldersrecursively() {
  var name = "backup";
  var rootfolders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);
  var newrootfolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFolder(name+" NEW");

  while (rootfolders.hasNext()) {
    var rootfolder = rootfolders.next(); 
    recursiveFolderCopy(rootfolder, newrootfolder);
  }


  function recursiveFolderCopy(folder, newfolder) {
    copyFilesinFolder(folder, newfolder);
    var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
    while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
      var subfolder = subfolders.next();
      var newsubfolder = newfolder.createFolder(subfolder.getName());
      recursiveFolderCopy(subfolder, newsubfolder);
    }
  }


  function copyFilesinFolder(folder, newfolder) {
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      try {
        var file = files.next();
        var filename = file.getName(); 
        file.makeCopy(filename, newfolder);
      } catch(e) {
        Logger.log(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: The Google Apps Script API fails for some special file types such as Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Currently google drive don't have a function/api to change owner to files and transfere the quota from a user to another. So i created a [colab](https://github.com/simone-viozzi/drive-transfere-ownership) script that transfere reccursively the ownership of files whose ownership can be transferred and than dowload from an user and reupload from the other user all the other files.